Include automatic incremental file versioning when rendering .rmd/.qmd files to pdf
Is there a way to include automatic incremental document versioning when working in markdown/rmarkdown/quarto? When I first render a file to pdf I want it to display version 1.0 and increment upwards from there every time the pdf is updated. Is this something that's possible?
I tried including a custom function based on the presence of a cache file but it didn't work. It seems that the YAML header option "version" is not accepted (I really convinced myself it did).
Here's my YAML header:
---
title: "Project: Example"
date: "April 2024"
documentclass: report
version: 1.0
---
This is my function:
cache_dir <- "./cache"

# Function to increment and return version number
version_number <- function() {
  if (!file.exists(file.path(cache_dir, ".RData"))) {
    version <- 1.0
    save(version, file = file.path(cache_dir, ".RData"))
  } else {
    load(file = file.path(cache_dir, ".RData"))
    version <- get("version") + 1.0
    save(version, file = file.path(cache_dir, ".RData"))
  }
  return(paste0("v", version))
}

This also does not work:
---
title: "Project: Example"
date: "April 2024"
documentclass: report
version: 1.0
---
Does anyone know how I can implement such behavior? I'm not looking for version control like Git, and I'm using Visual Studio Code, if that helps. Thanks!

If you were using RStudio, you could store the version number as a parameter in your R Markdown file. You could then also include a rendering chunk in the R Markdown file. Running the rendering chunk would update the version and render the file.
R Markdown File
---
title: "Project: Example"
output: pdf_document
date: "April 2024"
params:
  version: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r render, eval=FALSE, include=FALSE}
this_document <- function() {
  rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path
}

get_version <- function() {
  src <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$contents
  version_line <- grep("^  version: \\d+", src)
  as.numeric(sub("  version: ", "", src[version_line]))
}

set_version <- function(v) {
  src <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$contents
  version_line <- grep("^  version: \\d+", src)
  version_line_length <- nchar(src[version_line]) + 1
  version_range <- rstudioapi::document_range(
    rstudioapi::document_position(version_line, 1),
    rstudioapi::document_position(version_line, version_line_length)
  )
  rstudioapi::modifyRange(version_range, sprintf("  version: %i", v))
}

increment_version <- function() {
  v <- get_version()
  set_version(v + 1)
}

render <- function(input, ...) {
  increment_version()
  rstudioapi::documentSave(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$id)
  rmarkdown::render(input, ...)
}

render(this_document())
```

```{r}
sprintf("The current version of this document is %i.", params$version)
```

Output


One thing you could do is store the version number as a parameter in your R Markdown file and then use an external R Script to render the R Markdown file.
Contents of R Markdown
---
title: "Project: Example"
output: pdf_document
date: "April 2024"
params:
  version: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
sprintf("The current version of this document is %i.", params$version)
```


Contents of R Script
get_version <- function(x) {
  src <- readLines(x)
  version_line <- grep("  version: \\d+", src)
  as.numeric(sub("  version: ", "", src[version_line]))
}

set_version <- function(x, v) {
  src <- readLines(x)
  version_line <- grep("  version: \\d+", src)
  src[version_line] <- sprintf("  version: %i", v)
  writeLines(src, x)
}

increment_version <- function(x) {
  version <- get_version(x)
  set_version(x, version + 1)
}

render <- function(input, ...) {
  increment_version(input)
  rmarkdown::render(input, ...)
}

render("C:/Users/the-mad-statter/Documents/my_r_markdown.Rmd")

After editing the R Script to point to the desired R Markdown File, you could run it. The script will update the version number and then render the R Markdown file.
Output

